# How to set db rows info based on these specific parameters:

Tags: php, mysql, database

My database has a table :

`users` where i have the columns

```
cities, 
referrer, 
referrals, 
username 
id
```

How to set (either in the cron job or some other way) to automatically :

```
If a member "cities"=0
    Set "referrer" (id)=0
AND
    in referrers users row:  "referrals"=referrals-1
```

Each user may have 0 or more cities, if he has a referrer then the row "referrer" will store the id of referrer as such "referrer=(where id of referrer).

Basically what i want is members who have referrals with 0 cities loose these referrals when the cron job runs and at the same time set the referrer of those members to 0(none) .

Ive tried setting variables and other things but this seems too complex atm. Please examples with codes .

Comment: Start by showing us the code you have tried. It will help us understand an otherwise difficult to understand question

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Should be some SQL UPDATE queries, by the looks of it. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is simply `update users set referrals=0 where id not in
(select referrer from users)`